# Tkinter control scale and entry field with each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a scale and an input field which both control the same variable to give the user choice of which one they'd like to use. I've coded it a bit like this:

```
def scale_has_moved(value):
    entry_field.delete(0, END)
    entry_field.insert(0, str(float(value)))

    # Other functions I want the code to do

def entry_field_has_been_written(*args):
    value = float( entry_field.get() )
    scale.set(value)
```

This works, when I move the `scale` the `entry_field` gets written in and vice versa, and the other functions I want the code to do all happen. The obvious problem is the functions call each other in a loop, so moving the scale calls `scale_has_moved()` which calls the additional functions within and writes in the entry field, then because the entry field has been written in `entry_field_has_been_written()` gets called which in turn calls `scale_has_moved()` again, it doesn't go in an endless loop but it does everything at least twice everytime which affects performance.
Any clue how I'd fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same variable for both widgets, they will automatically stay in sync. You don't need your two functions at all. The following code illustrates the technique.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var, orient="horizontal")
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)

scale.pack(side="top", fill="x")
entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you but I still get the problem of the functions calling each other multiple times and slowing things down

Comment: @CWoody00: I think you missed the point. You don't need your two functions at all.